# Django admin interface: Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm

Tags: django, hash, passwords, admin, django-registration

I've made a register and login function which saves a user data to the database using the django User object. But when i register a user, the password linked to the user doesn't get hashed properly. This means that i have this error in the django admin interface: "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.". I've made sure to use the set_password.

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User_Information(models.Model):
    # Links UserProfile to a User model instance
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return username
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py

```
       from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from authentication.models import User_Information

    class User_Form(forms.ModelForm):
        # Using the PasswordInput widget to hide the entered content of the password field
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

        # Define the nested class. The default fields can be edited here, if you wish to exclude something.
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    # Checks if registration was successful. Changes to true if this is the case
    # Processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = User_Form(data=request.POST)
        # If the form is valid.
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Saves the user's data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()
            # Hash the password and updates the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save
            # Tell the template that registration was successful
            messages.success(request, 'You registered successfully')
        else:
            print user_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = User_Form()

    return render_to_response(
        'authentication/register.html',
        {'user_form': user_form},
        context)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to extend this form django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm to your needs?

Comment: you are welcome, i added it as answer for future generation of developers dealing with this problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to extend predefined form django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm to your needs.